# Sql Server 2008 Calculate nights between two dates but remove 31st night

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff

I have a booking table with the following information:

BookingID,(unique, not null)
StartDate, (not null)
EndDate (not null)

I need to calculate the number of nights someone remained in residence which I can do with a DATEDIFF between EndDate and StartDate. However, if someone is in residence for the entire month during a 31 day month we only charge them 30.

I'm not sure how to do this in SQL. I was thinking I would have to create a variable, calculate on a monthly basis and add to the variable, but that seems like it would be messy and take a very long time, especially towards the end of year. This needs to be done for about 5,000 records on a daily basis.

So:
If someone starts on 7/25/14 and ends 9/2/14, the nights is 38 not 39.
If someone starts on 10/2/14 and ends on 11/1/14, the nights is 30.
If someone starts on 10/2/14 and ends on 10/31/14, the nights is 29.

We will be calculating into the future so it doesn't matter if the end date is greater than the day the report is being ran.

Does anyone have any ideas how to accomplish this in the best way?

Comment: If datediff is 62, should the answer be 60?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first to create a lookup table with all the month with 31 days

Such as

```
DECLARE @month TABLE (start_date date,end_date date)

    INSERT INTO @month VALUES ('2014-07-01','2014-07-31'),('2014-08-01','2014-08-31'),('2014-10-01','2014-10-31'),('2014-12-01','2014-12-31') 
//populate all months in your calculate range
```

Then you can calculate the value with

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '2014-07-25', @end DATE = '2014-09-02'

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@start,@end) - 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @month WHERE start_date >= @start AND end_date <= @end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the integer part of the datediff divided by 31 :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2014-07-25', '2014-09-02') - DATEDIFF(day,'2014-07-25', '2014-09-02') / 31
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQLish solution is to create a calendar table that holds all the dates you will ever care about and any business meaning that those dates may have, such as "Is this a holiday?", "Is this off-season?", or "do we charge for this day?"

This may sound insane to someone accustomed to other programming languages, but it is perfectly sensible in the database world.  Business rules and business logic get stored as data, not as code.

Make this table and populate it:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar (
  [date] date
 ,[is_charged] bit
)
```

and then you can write code that is nearly plain English:

```
SELECT
  [BookingID]
 ,COUNT([date])
FROM BookingTable
INNER JOIN Calendar
  ON  [date] >= [StartDate]
  AND [date] <  [EndDate]
WHERE [is_charged] = 1
GROUP BY [BookingId]
```

When your business rules change, you just update the calendar instead of rewriting the code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I am planning to use a calendar table another aspect where we have specific dates that are not billed.  But since whether or not the date is billable depends on the length of each stay, I don't think this solution can be used.

Answer (score 0):

If I've read your question correctly then you can't actually use those solutions above which consist of a table of billable and non billable days because the 31st is billable unless the whole month was booked.

I reckon this is probably a job for a user defined function. Which runs up a total starting with the month that the start date is in and finishing with the month that the end date is in.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_BillableDays (@StartDate date, @EndDate date) 
 returns int
AS
BEGIN
IF @StartDate > @EndDate
BEGIN 
return null  --Error
END
DECLARE @Next date
DECLARE @MonthStart date
DECLARE @MonthEnd  date
DECLARE @NextMonthStart  date
DECLARE @n int =0
SET @Next = @StartDate
SET @MonthStart = DATEADD(day,1-DAY(@Next),@Next)
SET @NextMonthStart  = DATEADD(month,1,@MonthStart )
SET @MonthEnd = DATEADD(day,-1,@NextMonthStart)
WHILE DATEDIFF(month,@Next,@EndDate) >0
BEGIN
   SET @n = @n +
    CASE 
    WHEN DAY(@next) = 1 AND DAY(@MonthEnd) = 31 THEN 30
    WHEN DAY(@next) = 1 THEN DAY(@MonthEnd)
    ELSE 1+DAY(@MonthEnd) -DAY(@next)  END

    SET @MonthStart = @NextMonthStart  
    SET @NextMonthStart  = DATEADD(month,1,@MonthStart )
    SET @MonthEnd = DATEADD(day,-1,@NextMonthStart)
    SET @Next = @NextMonthStart  
END
--Month of the EndDate
   SET @n = @n +
   CASE 
   WHEN DAY(@next) = 1 AND DAY(@EndDate) = 31 THEN 29
   WHEN DAY(@next) = 1 THEN DAY(@EndDate)-1
   ELSE DAY(@MonthEnd) -DAY(@EndDate)  END
return  @n 
END
```

I tried it with some test dates

```
SELECT 
b.BookingID,
b.StartDate,
b.EndDate, 
dbo.FN_BillableDays (b.StartDate,b.EndDate) AS BillableDays 
FROM dbo.Booking  b
```

And got the following

```
BookingID   StartDate  EndDate    BillableDays
----------- ---------- ---------- ------------
1           2013-12-31 2014-01-02 2
2           2013-12-31 2014-01-30 30
3           2014-01-01 2014-01-30 29
4           2014-01-01 2014-01-31 29
5           2014-01-01 2014-02-01 30
6           2014-01-01 2014-02-02 31
7           2014-02-02 2014-02-01 NULL

(7 row(s) affected)
```

Which matches my understanding of the logic you want to implement but you may want to tweak the last bit which adds on the days for the final month. If they leave on the 31st do you want to give them their last night (30th to 31st) for free.

If you don't then delete the line
       WHEN DAY(@next) = 1 AND DAY(@EndDate) = 31 THEN 29

Comment: Thank you for this! Yes, that was why I didn't start with a calendar table, which was my initial thought, since whether the night is billable varies.  I haven't had a chance to test this out, but is where I thought I'd have to go. I'll let you know how it tests out tomorrow.

Comment: It might be worth caching the results in a lookup table and altering the function to check the lookup table, return a value if found and otherwise calculate the value (using the same method) and store it in the table. That way the billable days for each pair of values will only need to be calculated once.

You could even create a huge lookup table with every pair of dates you are ever likely to need, prepopulate it with this function and use that table for your regular process.

Ultimately you'll have to decide whether the performance impact of doing the calculation each time is acceptable

Comment: Yes, I have to account for performance.  @EricZ 's method works as well, so I need to determine which is more scalable and better for performance.  I also forgot to add, In February, if they stay the whole month, then they get billed 30 nights, not just 28.  I'm assuming I'll just have to add some more code to account for this when the month is 2?